# Should I query from varray or in nested cursor?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table in which the customer will define some names, whose data they want to copy to a different table. Timestamps will be copied to keep track of the latest data. In the table where the data is normally stored, its timestamp is broken into day_part and time_part, which are both RAW(3);

These are my tables:

**table_A**

```
name    VARCHAR2(1000)
```

**table_B**

```
name    VARCHAR2(1000)
id_num  INT
```

**table_C**

```
id_num      INT
day_part    RAW(3)
time_part   RAW(3)
value       NUMBER(20,5)
```

**table_D**

```
name        VARCHAR2(1000)
time_stamp  TIMESTAMP
```

The timestamp in table_D is created by a function with day_part and time_part as input.

I want to copy data from table_C, based on the names in table_A and the latest timestamp in table_D. This is part of a huge system, so I can't change the two RAWs to a single timestamp, it would cause a lot of problems.

My current solution is to first open a cursor to find the id_num given name in table_A, using

```sql
SELECT table_B.name, table_B.id_num
FROM table_A
INNER JOIN table_B
ON table_B.name = table_A.name;
```

The name and id_num are fetched into variables (current_name, current_id) to search for data in a second cursor, within the first. Before the second cursor is opened, I convert time_stamp to RAW:

```sql
SELECT MAX(time_stamp)
INTO stamp_variable
FROM table_D
WHERE name = current_name;

stampToRaw(last_dPart, last_tPart, stamp_variable);
```

Now the second cursor opens, which executes the query:

```
SELECT value, day_part, time_part
FROM table_C
WHERE id_num = current_id
AND ((day_part = lastdPart AND time_part > last_tPart)
    OR day_part > last_dPart);
```

If newer data is found, it is copied to a different table, and its timestamp is stored in table_D, to be used the next time it runs.
Is there a more efficient way of doing this that I can't see?
I'm not used to the PL/SQL way of thinking, so I apologize if there's an obvious answer to this.

Comment: Please can you [edit] your question to provide a complete [MRE] that includes DDL statements for the tables, DML statements for some sample data and a **complete** (but also minimal) example PL/SQL block that will run that demonstrates the problem. Trying to answer it with a half-working example and no data just makes it harder for us to help you.

Comment: Why not `SELECT value, timestamp
FROM table_B
WHERE name IN (SELECT id_num FROM table_A);`?

Comment: @MT0 Sorry, I was in a bit of a hurry, and apparently disoriented when asking this question. Edited to explain what is happening more accurately. I hope this is enough.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, neither of your options is "best". Nested loops promise to be slow.

Why wouldn't you simply join those two tables, e.g.

```
select a.id_num, a.name, b.value, b.timestamp
from a join b on a.id_num = b.id_num
where a.name = current_name;
```

and have everything right now, right here? If it must be PL/SQL, so be it; no problem in converting that into a procedure (or a function, whichever you prefer).

Comment: Nested loops aren't always slow; they can be the best option for retrieving the data (otherwise the optimizer wouldn't use them!). There is no point, however, in reinventing nested loops, so the rest of your answer stands *{:-)

Comment: @Boneist, thank you for the comment. What I meant to say was: row-by-row (in one loop) is slow. When that's multiplied by another loop which for the above row fetches bunch of information, again row-by-row, will be much slower than a single JOIN statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using a simple query:

```
SELECT
    A.NAME,
    A.ID_NUM,
    B.VALUE,
    B.TIMESTAMP
FROM
    TABLE_A A
    JOIN TABLE_B B ON ( A.NAME = B.NAME );
```

Cheers!!